# RStudio1.2.1335 quits when calling rattle() ver 2.5.0 due to RGtk2 2.20.36 using Mojave

Tags: r, rattle, rgtk2

A fatal error occurs when I installed RGtk2 2.20.36 on RStudio version 1.2.1335. I followed the steps recommended on [Installing Rattle on macOS](https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rattle/) using HomeBrew.

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.5
BuildVersion:   18F132

Traceback:
 1: .RGtkCall("S_gtk_widget_show", object, PACKAGE = "RGtk2")
 2: method(obj, ...)
 3: crv$rattleGUI$getObject("rattle_window")$show()
 4: rattle()
```

Comment: Does this occur in vanilla R as well?

Comment: Same error on R (3.6) : *** caught segfault *** adress 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'                          Traceback: 1: .RGtkCall("S_gtk_widget_show", object, PACKAGE = "RGtk2") 2: method(obj, ...) 3: crv$rattleGUI$getObject("rattle_window")$show() 4: rattle()

Comment: Same error happens on vanilla R ...

Comment: I have it working on R (4.02), with the same version of RGtk2 2.20.36, see [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1577717/399707) to [segfault rattle error, address0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'](https://superuser.com/q/1475536/399707)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (recommend by Yung-jin Lee) directly on the terminal:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

sudo port selfupdate

sudo port install pkgconfig

sudo port install gtk2 +x11

R CMD INSTALL RGtk2_x.xx.xx.tar.gz

R CMD INSTALL cairoDevice_x.xx.tar.gz
```

It worked for me.

Comment: You say that it was recommended by Yung-jin Lee, but where from? Do you have the link?